# Nested Routing with a Collection in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm getting an error: `No route matches {:action=>"sort", :controller=>"links"}`

I'm adapting from a non-nested example and am having trouble figuring out the nested routing.

Right now, my route looks like this:

```
resources :groups do
  resources :navbars do
    resources :links do
      collection { post :sort }
    end
  end
  post :add_user, on: :member
end
```

I am rendering a collection of links from navbar>show:

```
= render partial: 'links/link', collection: @navbar.links
```

and here's the collection, links>_link.html.haml:

```
%ul#links{"data-update-url" => sort_group_navbar_links_url}
  - @links.each do |faq|
    = content_tag_for :li, link do
      %span.handle [drag]
      = link.method_name
      = link.code
      = link.button
      = link.text
      = link_to 'Edit Link', edit_group_navbar_link_path(@group, @navbar, link), class: 'btn btn-mini'
      = link_to 'Delete', group_navbar_link_path(@group, @navbar, link), data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-mini'
```

My links_controller has the sort action:

```
def sort
  params[:link].each_with_index do |id, index|
    Link.update_all({display_order: index+1}, {id: id})
  end
  render nothing: true
end
```

Because my link collection is being rendered from the navbar>show page, it's not clear to me where my sort action should be located (in links_controller or in navbars_controller).

And my navbars_controller defines @links:

```
def show
  @links = @navbar.links.order("display_order")

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html  # show.html.erb
    format.json  { render :json => @navbar }
  end
end
```

Also here's the js for good measure (links.js.coffee):

```
jQuery ->
  $('#links').sortable
    axis: 'y'
    handle: '.handle'
    update: ->
      $.post($(this).data('update-url'), $(this).sortable('serialize'))
```

Maybe this last line also needs work to include the route?

I'm using rails 3.2.